# Placeholder in banner.txt are not replaced when deploying war file

Tags: spring-boot

I've built a spring boot application and I'm trying to customize the banner to display the version of my application.
After reading the documentation, I've managed to create a banner.txt in the classpath and added the **${application.formatted-version}** placeholder inside.
I've also managed to create a manifest file (using Gradle) containing the **Implementation-Version**.

Everything works fine when executing a jar file directly but when creating a war file, the banner is displayed but the version placeholder is not replaced.

After a bit of debugging, this method seems to be the source of the problem
**org.springframework.boot.ResourceBanner.getApplicationVersion()**

When running a war file, the call to 
**sourcePackage.getImplementationVersion()** always return null

The manifest file is located at the root of the war file /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
The application is deployed in a standalone tomcat 8.0.15

Any idea of what's wrong ?

Comment: Not an answer, but I can reproduce this. You don't even need to run it in tomcat, just packaging as a war and then running with `java -jar app.war` shows the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug/limitation in Tomcat. It fails to find the `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` from an exploded WAR file which causes its `ClassLoader` to define the package with a `null` implementation version. This has been fixed in Tomcat, but the fix hasn't made it into a release yet. It'll be in 8.0.25.

There's [some more information in this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3406) and [this is the change that was made to Tomcat](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?diff_format=h&view=revision&revision=1688897) if you're interested.